# Flutter - Save file in downloads folder (Need to use Media Store API)

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

my app was rejected by Google for policy violation.

> Issue: Need to use Media Store API or No Access to Files

*Here is the [Reference Link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media) provided in the rejection email.*

The following code runs fine and the file is downloaded in the "Downloads" folder.

Targeted SDK version and list of Android permissions used:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 31
```

Below method gets path for "Downloads" folder. I have currently hardcoded the path. This method also asks for permission at runtime and then finally it saves the pdf file:

```
Future<bool> savePdfFile(dynamic bytes) async {
    try {
        var directoryPath = "";
        
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
            if(
                (await _requestPermission(Permission.storage)) && 
                (await _requestPermission(Permission.accessMediaLocation)) && 
                (await _requestPermission(Permission.manageExternalStorage))
            ) {
              Directory dir = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');
              directoryPath = dir.path;
            }
        }

        if (directoryPath != "") {
            File saveFile = File(directoryPath + "/sample.pdf");
            await saveFile.writeAsBytes(bytes);

            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If I remove any permission the file is not saved. What should be done? stuck here, guys. TIA.

Comment: `Method to save pdf file:` We cannot see where you save that file.

Comment: Every app can create files in public Download folder. I dont understand what goes wrong. MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not needed.

Comment: `the file is not downloaded. ` Downloaded? You were trying to create a file... i cannot follow you.

Comment: Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download') the Downloads folder

Comment: Sorry my bad, I mean file is not saved when I remove MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: Again: You dont need MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Ads what has not being able to create a file in Download directory to do with downloading? This is about file creation or not?

Comment: So you are saying without MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE the file is created and saved in Download folder of mobile right? But it is not happening. Can you plz provide any sample for Flutter?

Comment: Sorry, i do not use Flutter

Comment: I am facing the same problem, have you get any solution of it, @ZainSMJ

Comment: No not yet. I have removed MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission and file is saved in "Android/data/app_folder/files"

Comment: Hi @ZainSMJ i am currently facing the same issue, i learnt that MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is needed only for android 10 and above, have you been able to solve this issue?.

Comment: HI @user7676575 have you found the solution to this problem?.